# How can I set supported device list

Tags: ios, air

I am developing with Adobe Air for IOS devices. However, I don't want to support iPhone3GS for some reason which means I don't want user can download from app store or don't let these devices install my app.

I want to know how to implement or configure this feature. Thank You

Comment: Well you could add in the info.plist the need for a front facing camera. But Why don't you want to support the iPhone 3GS, since it runs iOS 6 it is still an update device. Also if you do add the install restriction, some update iPod Touchs can't install you to and what about the iPad?

Comment: because, we cannot solve performance problem on iPhone3GS. But we still support iPad. so it seems that we cannot use front facing camera flag to handle this problem. I suppose it should be configurable on Apple developer pages, but I didn't find it. Anyway, still thanks for your help @rckoenes. I learned how to specify need for a front facing camera at least.